# App does not receive GCM messages after reboot on Android 5.0

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, react-native

I use `react-native-gcm-android` and `react-native-system-notification` packages to manage GCM notifications (Android), everything works fine on Android 4.x but on 5.0 (ASUS_Z00AD) after reboot GCM messages not appear, log shows me

```
W/BroadcastQueue(  639): Reject to launch app com.Sgoomys.Main/10246 for broadcast: App Op 48
W/GCM-DMM ( 1824): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.Sgoomys.Main (has extras) }
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` all the settings are made according the packages documentation:

```
<permission 
    android:name="com.Sgoomys.Main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.Sgoomys.Main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
   ...
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      <category android:name="com.Sgoomys.Main" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <service android:name="com.oney.gcm.GcmRegistrationService"/>
  <service android:name="com.oney.gcm.BackgroundService"></service>

  <service
    android:name="io.neson.react.notification.GCMNotificationListenerService"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <receiver
    android:exported="false"
    android:name="com.oney.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.oney.gcm.GCMReceiveNotification" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Google Play Services library is `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the puzzle...

Application doesn't start at boot-up because it was blocked by Asus utility "Auto-start manager" - all recently installed apps are blocked by default.

So now I will add a check for `com.asus.mobilemanager` package with alert and button to start this utility and unblock autorun, but I think the correct way will be detect **all** possible blocking software and inform user about it.